# How to return special value when objected is casted to an array?

Tags: php

There is a magic method `__toString`, which would be triggered if an object is used in a string context or casted to such, e.g.

```
<?php 

class Foo {
    public function __toString() { 
        return 'bar'; 
  } 
} 

echo (string) new Foo(); // return 'bar';
```

Is there a similar function that would be triggered when an object is castend into an `(array)`?

Comment: Why would you ever cast an object into an array without knowing its type (more specifically, if it's not known to be `stdClass`)? And if you do know its type, why does it need casting?

Comment: I know that it is an object. The layer that the value is being passed though does not utilise the Object functionality and is limited to array. Now I am doing this by simply providing a custom method `flatten`. Asked the question simply out of curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

No, but there is the [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface, which allows you to use a class as an array. To get looping functionality a la `foreach` you will need to interface [`IteratorAggregate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php) or [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php). The former is easier to use if you have an internal array that you are using because you only need to override one method (which provides an instance of [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php)), but the latter allows you more fine-grain control over iterating.

Example:

```
class Messages extends ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate {
    private $messages = array();

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return array_key_exists($offset, $this->messages);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->messages[$offset];
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->messages[$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->messages[$offset]);
    }

    public function getIterator() {
        return new ArrayIterator($this->messages);
    }
}

$messages = new Messages();
$messages[0] = 'abc';
echo $messages[0]; // 'abc'

foreach($messages as $message) { echo $message; } // 'abc'
```

Comment: Thanks, though I am interested in casting the value into an array for performance reasons.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas How would casting to an array help performance?

Comment: Surely accessing, iterating, etc. an object is slower (and more memory consuming) than performing the same operations on a bare array.

Comment: @GajusKuizinas: "Surely"? Why? Actually, IIRC if the object is of a known class type it is *faster*.

Comment: Just give it a try and share your findings.

Answer (score 2):

This may not being exactly what you may have expected, because what you expect isn't available as a language feature of PHP (unfortunately) but here comes a well known workaround:

Use [`get_object_vars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) for this:

```
$f = new Foo();
var_dump(get_object_vars($f));
```

It will return an associative array with property names as indexes and theirs values. Check this example:

```
class Foo {

    public $bar = 'hello world';

    // even protected and private members will get exported:
    protected $test = 'I\'m protected';
    private $test2 = 'I\'m private';


    public function toArray() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }   

}

$f = new Foo();
var_dump($f->toArray());
```

*Output:*

```
array(2) {
  'bar' =>
  string(11) "hello world"
  'test' =>
  string(13) "I'm protected"
  'test2' =>
  string(13) "I'm private"
}
```